# Sending input to Google homepage

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.google.com') 
elem_list = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"#gLfyf")
text_area = browser.find_element(By.text_area,'#APjFqb.gLFyf')

text_area.send_keys("https://www.amazon.com")
```

i tried different ways to solve this problem but i can't get it ,so fir that i need a clear solution for the above mentioned problem
``

Comment: what's the "above mentioned problem"? (i.e. what exactly is the issue?)

Comment: When using `By.CLASS_NAME`, drop the `#` from before the class name. You only want the `#` if using `By.CSS_SELECTOR`